# Como configurar o Visual Studio Code para abrir o console em uma nova janela?

Tags: node.js, debug, visual-studio-code

Em versões anteriores o Console do **Visual Studio Code** era aberta em uma janela externa ao **Visual Studio Code**, mas nas novas versões essa tela de Console passou a ser aberta dentro do próprio **Visual Studio Code**, o que atrapalha muito a depuração, pois a janela de console ocupa um espaço considerável, o que diminui o tamanho das demais janelas. Podemos ver isso na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, com a janela de console aberta dentro do **Visual Studio Code**, as janelas dos arquivos de código fonte acabam ficando muito estreitas, e para visualizar todo o código eu tenho que fechar a tela do console.

Antes, porém, era possível manter as duas janelas abertas sem uma interferir na área da outra. Isso ocorria por que o console do **Visual Studio Code** era aberto em uma janela externa ao aplicativo, e assim eu podia ver tanto o arquivo de código fonte e a tela de console simultaneamente, sem que a tela de console ficasse atrapalhando a área do código fonte.

Minha dúvida é se existe uma configuração para fazer com que o **Visual Studio Code** volte a abrir o console novamente em uma janela externa e como configurá-lo para isso.

Comment: Resetar as configurações do VS é uma opção? Caso queira https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @PauloHDSousa nesse caso não, por que já está com as configurações padrão. Olhei todas as opções de configuração e não encontrei nenhuma relacionada com essa tela de console.

Comment: Normalmente em todas versões do `Visual Studio`, basta clicar com o botão direito no título da aba (no caso, `Debug Console`) e selecionar a opção `Float`.

Porém em versões novas a *Microsoft* vem tirando esse recurso por causa de feedbacks no seu programa de `Insiders`.

Comment: você já resolveu?

Comment: @durtto Recentemente eles fizeram uma nova alteração no posicionamento da janela do console, colocando essa janela agora na horizontal, dividindo a área da tela pra ficar metade código fonte e metade console. Eu achei bem melhor do que o jeito que estava quando fiz essa pergunta, mas ainda assim eu preferia muito mais quando era uma janela separada. Acho que o único jeito de concertar isso é fazer uma votação apoiando o retorno dessa janela de console para como era originalmente. Mesmo assim, os desenvolvedores do Visual Studio Code devem ter seus motivos pra terem feito isso.

Comment: Entendo. Então tente criar uma resposta para sua pergunta. Assim você pode ajudar outras pessoas não deixando a pegunta vaga.

Comment: @Ulysses pesquisei a respeito e encontrei algo que talvez possa te ajudar, trata-se de trocar o console padrão no vs code pelo ConEmu (conemu.github.io), abaixo seguem alguns links espero que ajude. [Extensão para definir o console no vs code](https://github.com/vilic/vscode-console) [ConEmu VS Code](https://app.market.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vilicvane.console)

Comment: @CharlesWilliam dei uma olhada nos links que você me passou. Apesar de eles não terem sido a solução que eu estava procurando, de uma forma ou de outra eles acabaram me levando a pesquisar do jeito certo no Google, e encontrei na documentação do Visual Studio Code o que a gente precisa fazer pra rodar o console na janela externa. É coisa simples, e adicionei uma resposta explicando como resolver esse problema. Obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: @durtto Sim. Acabei de resolver.

Comment: Eu ja passo pelo problema inverso. Quero que meu terminal abra no VS Code e não destachado.

Comment: @acacio.martins olha minha resposta abaixo. Pode ser que dê certo pra vc configurando a opção "externalConsole" para ter o valor "false".

Comment: @UlyssesAlves por incrível que pareça consegui hoje. Tive que desativar o "Use Legacy Console" nas propriedades do prompt. Também desmarquei a opção "Features/Terminal/ Integrated: Inherit Env... esse último duvido porque há uma nota dizendo que não funciona para Windows. Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente descobri como se faz para abrir o console em uma janela externa ao Visual Studio Code.

De acordo com a [documentação de depuração do Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations), basta adicionar, no arquivo **launch.json**, a entrada `"externalConsole": true` ao JSON da configuração do runner que você deseja executar com o console aberto na janela externa, como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente, o valor dessa entrada é `false` por padrão, e por isso é necessário alterá-la para `true` nas configurações dos runners que você deseja executar com o console na janela externa.

Por exemplo, a minha configuração ficou da seguinte forma:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        ...
        "externalConsole": true,
        ...
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Olhei a documentação aqui está a solução.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]